# Не получается подключить js framework Hightcharts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой highcharts. Создал проект mvc. Скачал к проекту библиотеку. Создал свою вьюшку. И нашёл пример на их официальном сайте сайте highsoft. Вот код страницы:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Diagramm";
}

@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
        new Highcharts
        {
            Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
            {
                Width = 1087,
                Height = 400,
                Type = ChartType.Area
            },
            Series = new List<Series>
            {
                new AreaSeries
                {
                    Name = "USA",
                    Data = @ViewData["usaData"] as List<AreaSeriesData>
                },
                new AreaSeries
                {
                    Name = "USSR/Russia",
                    Data = @ViewData["russiaData"] as List<AreaSeriesData>
                }
            }
        }
        , "chart")
    )
```

И код контроллера:

```
public ActionResult Diagramm()
        {
            List<double?> usaValues = new List<double?> {
                null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 };

            List<double?> russiaValues = new List<double?> {
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000 };

            List<AreaSeriesData> usaData = new List<AreaSeriesData>();
            List<AreaSeriesData> russiaData = new List<AreaSeriesData>();

            usaValues.ForEach(p => usaData.Add(new AreaSeriesData { Y = p }));
            russiaValues.ForEach(p => russiaData.Add(new AreaSeriesData { Y = p }));

            ViewData["usaData"] = usaData;
            ViewData["russiaData"] = russiaData;

            return View();
        }
```

Но при запуске страницы, диаграмма не появляется. В отладке клиента увидел ошибки, при попытке создания Highcharts. Как я понимаю этот код со страницы преобразуется в javascript. Но возникает ошибка:

```
data.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at data.js:9
    at data.js:9
highcharts-3d.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at highcharts-3d.js:8
    at highcharts-3d.js:8
heatmap.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at heatmap.js:8
    at heatmap.js:8
highcharts-more.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at highcharts-more.js:8
    at highcharts-more.js:8
funnel.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at funnel.js:9
    at funnel.js:9
exporting.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at exporting.js:9
    at exporting.js:9
heatmap.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at heatmap.js:8
    at heatmap.js:8
treemap.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at treemap.js:9
    at treemap.js:9
drilldown.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at drilldown.js:9
    at drilldown.js:9
solid-gauge.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at solid-gauge.js:9
    at solid-gauge.js:9
Diagramm:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at createChartchart (Diagramm:52)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Diagramm:52)
```

Как я понимаю ругается на подключённые ссылки. Но я делал всё как указано на лицензионном сайте. Подскажите пожалуйста что тут не так?

Comment: основной js файл то где (`highcharts.js`)? зы: js-скрипты через бандлы подключаются обычно

Comment: @teran уже разобрался с проблемой. P.S. highcharts это не скрипт а framework.

Comment: называйте как хотите. js библиотека это. Если разобрались, то напишите ответ на свой вопрос.